# Transfer a matrix into an array

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem that asked me to operate a double subscripted array by using a single-subscripted array. Hence, the question is: how can a double-subscripted array be transformed into a single-subscripted array? or if it can't be transformed.. How can you operate a double-subscripted through a single-subscripted array?
For example:

```
int matrix[ m ][ n ];
   //How can you transform matrix into array? Or operate it?
int array[ m * n ];
```

Basically, the problem asks this: "Create a class `DoubleSubscriptedArray`. At construction time, the class should be able to create an array of any number of rows and any number of columns.The underlying representation of the double-subscripted array should be a single-subscripted array of integers with `rows * columns` number of elements"

Comment: How do you want to map the elements?

Comment: Use two loops: one by `m` and another one by `n`?

Comment: Please post the actual declarations of those two arrays, not psuedo-code.  The answer depends highly on how you declared those two arrays.  For example, you can't declare arrays like that if `m` and/or `n` are variables.

Comment: There must be tens of thousands of examples on how to do it here on SO alone, not to mention millions on the wider Internet.

Comment: You can simply copy the data into the new array. For an `m * n` matrix the element at `(x, y)` is projected to the index `i = y * n + x` (depending if you have row or column major order).

Comment: As a hint for figuring out yourself, rememeber that `matrix` is an array *of arrays*. And that arrays are stored contiguously. I also recommend that you draw it out on paper to help you understand, and figuring out the possible arithmetic needed.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer:

```cpp
int array[m * n];

for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x) {
    array[y * m + x] = matrix[x][y];
  }
}
```

Where:

- `y` - row number
- `x` - column number

Now you need to serialize all rows into one:

```
row_no/col_no | 0 | 1 | 2 |
______________|___|___|___|
      0       | 1 | 2 | 3 |   <-- matrix data
      1       | 4 | 5 | 6 |

         ||
        \  /
         \/
array_no   0  1  2  3  4  5
           |  |  |  |  |  |
         [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]  <-- array data

array_no = row_no * number_of_rows + col_no
```

You can **[TEST](https://ideone.com/yclE0t)** it :)

P.S You can also do it like this:

```cpp
int* array = (int*)matrix;
```

It is version without copying :)

Comment: This is okay, but this also doesn't account for row major versus column major matrices.

Comment: That worked great, but why did  you put array[y * m + x] ?

Comment: @FrancisCugler What do you mean?

Comment: You are using a double for loop to traverse a single array. You are representing a 2D grid as a 1D array of elements. In stored computer memory they are almost always in 1D array when they are on the stack. If there are heap allocations then at least each row or column is contiguous then the next. Let's say we have a matrix that is 3x2. It has 6 elements and it is on the stack; that means you will have in memory `T t[6]`. Using a double loop to traverse the `{m,n}` coordinates using the formula `[y * m + x]` gives you one of the two either it be row major or column major...

Comment: ... continued. For example using row major versus column major of a 3x2 matrix: one representation in contiguous memory would be `{ {0,1,2}, {3,4,5} }` where these are the indices into a single dimensional array, the other representation in contiguous memory would be `{ {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5} }` again with the same indices into the 1D array. This may not seem like a big concern here but if you ever get into 2D or 3D graphics applications this will then matter.

Comment: What I was getting at is that your answer is a single solution to a problem set that has 2 possible valid solutions. The only difference here is how the user intends to represent their matrices...

Comment: The elements will always be stored from indices `[0,5]` but do they want that 1D array to represent a `NxM` matrix in row major order or do they want to represent it in a `column major` order. In a `2x2` matrix having row major the elements by index would be `0 = [1,1], 1 = [1,2], 2 = [2,1], 3 = [2,2]` and that same matrix in column major would be `0 = [1,1], 1 = [2,1], 3 = [1,2], 3 = [2,2]` I hope this helps to clarify the difference between row and column major matrix representations within a 1D contiguous array.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is stored as m times n elements contiguously in memory. What you can do is interpret the first element of your matrix as a int*, and you have your array. It prevents copying the elements.

```
int main()
{
    int matrix[3][3] = { {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1} };
    int* array = &matrix[0][0];

    // int array[9] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to copy your elements, you can try

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    int matrix[3][3] = { {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1} };
    int array[9];

    std::memcpy(&array[0], &matrix[0][0], sizeof(array));

    // int array[9] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recalculate index of one dimension array to store the coresponding value of two dimensional array.

If you need to copy, eficient approuch would be to copy raw by row from two dim array to one dim, cause multidimensional arrays are stored in raw mayor order,
and index can be calculated as

oneDimIndex = row*n+col

where you are fetching element at matrix[row,col]

And after, you can retrieve content from one dimension array with same calculation.